# Is there a way in VBA to specify the scaling of conditional formatting such that negative numbers are coded in red?

Tags: vba, excel, conditional-formatting

Wordy question but I am doing some interval based conditional formatting to work around hardcoded conditional formatting since former always take precedence over the latter. Essentially color codes between the hardcoded headers but in some instances, I only have one line between the hardcoded colors so a three scale conditional formatting will by default highlight a negative number in green; how can I force it in VBA to highlight negatives in red?

```
End With
With Range(Replace(range_, "#", "N")).FormatConditions.AddColorScale(3)
End With
```

Answer (score 0):

Based this [Post](http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/738314-visual-basic-applications-conditional-formatting.html), I created a method to modify the color scales.

> SetColorScale Range(Replace(range_, "#", "N"))

```
Sub SetColorScale(rng As Range)
    With rng
        .FormatConditions.AddColorScale ColorScaleType:=2
        .FormatConditions(.FormatConditions.Count).SetFirstPriority
        With .FormatConditions(1)
            With .ColorScaleCriteria(1)
                .Type = xlConditionValueLowestValue
                .FormatColor.Color = vbRed
                .FormatColor.TintAndShade = 0
            End With
            With .ColorScaleCriteria(2)
                .Type = xlConditionValueHighestValue
                .FormatColor.Color = vbGreen
                .FormatColor.TintAndShade = 0
            End With
        End With
    End With

End Sub
```